# Can Import statements in a module be available to the main script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make import statements from a python module, available in the main python script?

**my_module.py**

```
import pandas as pd

def data():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 6),
                        'B': range(10, 0, -2),
                        'C': range(10, 5, -1)
                        })

    return df1
```

**my_scrpit.py**

```
import my_module

# successfully retruns my dataframe
df = my_module.data()

# successfully queries my dataframe
print(df.query('A > B'))

# So, pandas methods are available in the context of my module where it is imported

# Create new dataframe fails unless pandas is imported in my_script.py
# blank_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

I can work around the failure noted above by simply importing pandas in my_module.py, but it feels like a mistake to import the same library twice.

Comment: Try `my_module.pd`

Comment: Yes, modules imported in the module are available to the main script but in an indirect way. It will work only for the functions / classes defined in the module. If you try to use the same module inside the main script explicitly then it will show an error. You will have to access it via the imported module like : module.pd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your imported modules are cached in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) and the import machinery will first look there to retrieve a to-be-imported module. So all that extra import does, is a dictionary lookup which is O(1).

When you do `my_module.pd` a similar lookup happens, but having `import pandas as pd` in your main module has the advantage that it is clear what your intention is (i.e. use the pandas module).

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

its perfectly fine to import pandas in both places (python is smart enough to not actually reload the whole module)...

or you can access it as `my_module.pd.DataFrame`